# What can I do to pass a list from C# to F#?

Tags: c#, f#

I know that the f# list is not the same at the c# List. What do I need to do to be able to pass a list of ints from a c# application to an f# library? I'd like to be able to use pattern matching on the data once it's in the f# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it.

The FSharp code:

```
let rec FindMaxInList list = 
   match list with
   | [x] -> x
   | h::t -> max h (FindMaxInList t)
   | [] -> failwith "empty list"

let rec FindMax ( array : ResizeArray<int>) =
   let list = List.ofSeq(array)
   FindMaxInList list
```

The c Sharp code:

```
    List<int> myInts = new List<int> { 5, 6, 7 };
    int max = FSModule.FindMax(myInts);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
Seq.toList : IEnumerable<'a> -> list<'a>
```

to convert any `IEnumerable<'a>` `seq` to an F# list. Note that F# lists are immutable; if you want to work with the mutable list, you don't need to do anything special, but you won't be able to use pattern matching. Or, rather, you *can* define active patterns for `System.Collections.Generic.List<'a>`; it's just a bad idea.

Comment: Just wondering, but why wouldn't a person want to write a few active patterns that operate on C# lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a sequence of ints - it's basically anything that supports `IEnumerable<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference C# Assemblies from F# projects. Expose your list via a referenced assembly.