# Converting between C# List and F# List

Tags: c#, f#

Remark: This is a self-documentation, but if you have any other suggestions, or if I made any mistakes/miss out something obvious, I would really appreciate your help.

Sources:

[convert .NET generic List to F# list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105165/convert-net-generic-list-to-f-list)

[What can I do to pass a list from C# to F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390176/what-can-i-do-to-pass-a-list-from-c-sharp-to-f)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kf43ys3(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1

---

I am a beginner in F# and C#, and I want to convert a C# List to an F# List, and vice versa. The code/commands for doing so changes depending on where is your code (in C# or F#).

Please see my answer below. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to take the answer here and put it in an answer, and not keeping the answer in the question itself.

Comment: Noted. I moved my answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 28):

Inside a C# document, I can use `ListModule.OfSeq` and `.ToList()`, like this:

```
// Currently inside a C# document
var CS_list = new List<int> {1,2,3}; 
var FS_list = ListModule.OfSeq(CS_List); // Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule
var CS_converted_back = FS_List.ToList();
```

Inside an F# document, I can use `Seq.toList`  and `ResizeArray<_>`, like this:

```
// Currently inside an F# document
let FS_list = [1;2;3]
let CS_list = ResizeArray<int> FS_list // System.Collections.Generic.List
let FS_converted_back = Seq.toList CS_list
```

If I made any mistakes, or if I miss out something obvious, please let me know.

Comment: You can use `Seq.toList` or `List.ofSeq`. The question is why you anyway want to convert as the `Seq` module has almost the same functions as the `List` module.

Comment: @DavidRaab, lists works much better with pattern matching, but in general I agree, when working with other .net languages, just stick with Seq.

Comment: @monoceres Yeah its true, and i don't think it matters much. Pattern-Matching on list is useful for writing your own low-level recursive functions. You also can write them with `List.head` and `List.tail` instead of using pattern matching. Those then translate nicely to `Seq.head` and `Seq.tail`. But in that case I guess it is anyway better to use the `seq {}` computation expression.