# Abbreviation (alternate name) of Dictionary in F#

Tags: c#, f#

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kf43ys3(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1

[Converting between C# List and F# List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271222/converting-between-c-sharp-list-and-f-list)

---

Is there an abbreviation/alternate name of the Dictionary class "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary" in F#?

For example, the C# List type "System.Collections.Generic.List" has an abbreviation called "ResizeArray" in F#.

So, if I am working with a C# list in F#, I can use "ResizeArray", instead of using "open System.Collections.Generic" at the start of my file (because that will cause conflict between the C# List module and the F# List module, e.g. see the code example from the Microsoft webpage linked above)

Is there a keyword in F# that is a abbreviation for "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary"? So that I don't need to use "open System.Collections.Generic" and cause potential conflict between C#List and F#List.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# supports type abbreviation all on its own. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-abbreviations

```
type type-abbreviation = type-name
```

So you can abbreviate the dictionary type on your own:

```
type ResizeDictionary<'a,'b> = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<'a,'b>
```