# Passing a list from C# to F#, how to specify the parameter is a list?

Tags: f#

With the following C# code

```
var MyList = new List<MyClass>();
SomeFSharpFunc(MyList);
```

on the F# side:

```
let SomeFSharpFunc (MyList: ???What do I put here so I know it's a list) =
```

I don't know to how express that the incoming parameter is a list.

Also, do I need to duplicate the C# class as a F# type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use

```
open System

let SomeFSharpFunc (MyList: System.Collections.Generic.List<MyClass>) = ...
```

but you should consider using `seq<MyClass>` instead (which is [equivalent to `IEnumerable<MyClass>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences)) if you don't need full power of `System.Collections.Generic.List`, especially since in F# "list" generally refers to [a very different data structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/lists).

See also [Converting between C# List and F# List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271222/converting-between-c-sharp-list-and-f-list).

> Also, do I need to duplicate the C# class as a F# type?

No.

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.List<'a>` has a more convenient alias in F#: `ResizeArray<'a>`